# What is recommended way to compare ReflectionOnlyType with Type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have realized that I cannot directly compare types from reflection only loaded assemblies with types resolved by `typeof`, even they both are from the same assembly.

I am currently using:
 `reflectionOnlyType.AssemblyQualifiedName == type.AssemblyQualifiedName`.

What is the recommended way?

Comment: Can you provide an example? because when I execute the following code I get true : 
Type reflectionType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName == reflectionType.AssemblyQualifiedName);

Comment: I also get true. (But I am not sure whether it is a recommended way to do so.) Btw. I think you are not using `ReflectionOnlyType`, since you can compare them directly without `AssemblyQualifiedName`.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a definitive answer, but it's a bit better than what's in the comments.

Having just asked myself the same question, I did start with AQN equivalency as a first step.  The problem with that is that if the assembly isn't signed, it is trivial to make a duplicate assembly with the same AQN.  (Note, I'm not coming from a security aspect; if you're loading assemblies you shouldn't rely on this answer to keep bad code from executing within your application)

Another option is to use `Type.GUID`, which [some random people on the internet say](https://ayende.com/blog/3095/system-type-guid-stability) is generated deterministically, but includes properties of the Type that can be controlled by the programmer.  Therefore the possibility for collisions still remain.  (And this shouldn't be used for security purposes)

There doesn't seem to be a better choice than one of the above (pls answer if I'm wrong!).  If you're reflecting and loading from the same folder (e.g., your bin folder), then using AQN should be adequate. `Type.GUID` gives a little bit better protection from collisions, and it *feels better* than using a string comparison.

If you really *really* need to know, you'd probably have to go overboard, comparing cryptographic hashes of both containing assemblies to verify they are the same, then use the AQN comparison and possibly other attributes of the Type.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by loading the `System.ReflectionOnly` type using the runtime type I have. That seems to be the safest way:

```
// Comes from an assembly loaded as reflection only
var reflectionOnlyTypeFromSomeAssembly = GetItFromSomewhere();

// Comes from an assembly that is running
var reflectionOnlyTypeFromRuntimeType = 
        Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(typeof(myType).AssemblyQualifiedName, false, true); 

// Now you can compare
if (reflectionOnlyTypeFromSomeAssembly == reflectionOnlyTypeFromRuntimeType) 
{
  // do something?
}
```

Comment: It is using `AssemblyQualifiedName` to resolve the ReflectionOnlyType. Is this solution safer than `reflectionOnlyType.AssemblyQualifiedName == type.AssemblyQualifiedName`? If yes, what are the reasons?

Comment: As long as the reflected assembly remains reflection only you should be safe. I have no strong reason but I prefer this case because 1) I think it makes the distinction between RuntimeType and ReflectionOnlyType obvious to anyone reading the code late on and 2) if the implementation of ReflectionOnlyType == operator gets updated for some reason I'd benefit from that. Actually should have called .Equals instead.